# Диалог открытия файла в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Подскажите, пожалуйста, диалог для открытия файла в WPF. Я знаю, что есть FileDialog в WinForms, но хочу обойтись по возможности без WinForms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используй Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog, во всяком случае в [обзоре диалоговых окон](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx) в МСДН используется именно он.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "Text documents (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        dialog.FilterIndex = 2;

        Nullable<bool> result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document
            string filename = dialog.FileName;
        }
```